# Injection of beans in JavaServer faces

Tags: jsf, javabeans, cdi, code-injection

I have two Session Scoped beans.

```
import javax.inject.Named;
import javax.enterprise.context.SessionScoped;
import java.io.Serializable;

@Named
@SessionScoped
public class PollsBean implements Serializable {
    private long id;
    private String title;
    ......
    get...
    set...
}



import javax.enterprise.context.SessionScoped;
import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.inject.Named;
import java.io.Serializable;

@Named
@SessionScoped
public class ChartBean implements Serializable {

    @Inject private PollsBean currentPoll;
     ... 
     public void someMethod(){
        Long curid = currentPoll.getId();
     }
}
```

So, when I open page which is using PollsBean, all works fine, all bean fields is initialized. After that I go to second page, which is using ChartBean and call someMethod(), and get NullPointerException. Why I can’t use initialized  SessionScoped Bean?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have a beans.xml file inside your META-INF or WEB-INF folder.

http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gjbnz.html

Comment: I have only empty build.xml file in web_war_exploded\WEB-INF\classes folder

Comment: Well, there must be a beans.xml (it can be empty) under the WEB-INF folder in case of a web app. Otherwise CDI won't scan the classpath for injection points.